# Genymotion not launching virtual devices

Tags: android, virtualbox, genymotion

I have created a new virtual device on Genymotion but I can not get it to run.
When I click on the "Start" button on the Genymotion GUI nothing happens.

[image]

I was able to run the virtual device from Virtual Box. The virtual device is apparently well configured, with internet working and all.

[image]

My current environment:

- OS X 10.10.1
- Genymotion 2.3.1
- Virtual Box 4.3.20 r96996

It is worth mentioning that I recently formatted the computer and installed everything (even Yosemite) from scratch, so I could me missing a dependency or something.

Any help or tip on how to fix it or get logs to know what the real problem is will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Have similar situation, including recent reinstall. Genymotion logs show just `Jan 5 21:14:23 [Genymotion] [Debug] Starting player at  "/Applications/Genymotion.app/Contents/MacOS"`, then nothing else. Have had success manually starting the device with the [instructions here](https://www.genymotion.com/#!/support?chapter=start-virtual-devices-command-prompt#faq). Note: instructions are obsolete - `genyshell` is currently in `Genymotion Shell.app`.

Comment: @user3452758  have you been able to solve this problem? I am still experiencing this, even after a fresh install of Genymotion.

Comment: @david.schreiber Sorry, no. Just set up an alias as a workaround.

Comment: @robert-estivill did you fix this?

Comment: No, had to format the computer for other reasons and after reinstalling it started working just fine. Weird

Answer (score 3):

I meet the same problem, but I find a way to start vm

go to `/Applications/Genymotion.app/Contents/MacOS`

and type the following command *(change to your vm name)*:

`./player -n "Google Nexus 4 - 4.2.2 - API 17 - 768x1280"`

Comment: You can also try to look. for `/Applications/Genymotion.app/Contents/MacOS/player.app/Contents/MacOS`

Answer (score 1):

have you configurated virtual device path to C:\Users\"computer name"\AppData\Local/Genymobile/Genymotion/deployed/"your android" ?

Answer (score 1):

I am using Genymotion for MAC, I was facing the same issue on my machine. I have done the following steps to solve this issue, hope this might help you as well:

1. Remove Genymotion and Virtual box
2. Reinstall Genymotion and Virtual box
3. Restart your machine.
4. Now start your genymotion and it should work fine.

**Download Links:**

Genymotion: https://www.genymotion.com/desktop/

VirtualBox: https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads

Answer (score 0):

for ubuntu users ,from the terminal add this command

> chmod +x -R /home/"your user name"/genymotion/